# Lftp default timeout and retry?

Tags: cron, ftp

Where can I find the defaults for `lftp`? Eg `net:max-retries` and `net:timeout`.

I'm asking because I get some `**** Data socket error (Connection timed out) - reconnecting` message in my lftp debug log. And it seems to retry forever if I don't quit the process manually. Which is bad for cron jobs.

Questions:

How could I explicit set the timeout and retries for one special script, which is as follows:

```
lftp -c "
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
lcd $SOURCEFOLDER
mirror --delete --verbose $FSOURCE $FTARGET
exit
"
```

And how could I catch any sync errors in the batch file above, so that I could eg send an email notification on max timeouts?

Comment: Are you by any chance looking for the `--while-ok` switch mentioned in the [man page?](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lftp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still I don't know how to find out the defaults. But could change them as follows:

```
lftp -c "
set net:timeout 5;
set net:max-retries 3;
set net:reconnect-interval-multiplier 1;
set net:reconnect-interval-base 5;
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
lcd $SOURCEFOLDER
mirror --delete --verbose $FSOURCE $FTARGET
exit
"
```

Comment: try set -d to view default value of lftp variable. if net:max-retries is set to 0 means unlimited. 1 means no retries.

Comment: try echo $? lftp should return a value other then 0 in case of errors

Comment: Of course `$?` gives the exit code if lftp exists with error. BUT the problem here is that by default lftp tried to reconnect endless times by default. So the exitcode evaluation would never take place, as the code is never reached.

Comment: did you try set -d to view default value? I guess that max-retries is set to 0, this is why your command did not end. So, I think your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I find the defaults for lftp?

From inside lftp prompt:

```
lftp :~> set -a
```

This will list all the defaults for lftp on your system.

lftp has context specific help. So you can type:

```
lftp :~> help set
```

Which returns:

```
Usage: set [OPT] [<var> [<val>]]
Set variable to given value. If the value is omitted, unset the variable.
Variable name has format ``name/closure'', where closure can specify
exact application of the setting. See lftp(1) for details.
If set is called with no variable then only altered settings are listed.
It can be changed by options:
 -a  list all settings, including default values
 -d  list only default values, not necessary current ones
```

Answer (score -1):

/etc/lftp.conf

This is the default settings file for lftp on our systems.

You can simply add lines to this as per the settings in membersound's answer above.

Comment: Can you add a few more content that would answered at OP question? You could explain what to modify for example, so please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1190278/edit) your answer