# When to use LFTP -c versus -e versus nothing

Tags: ftp, execute-command

Hi someone tell me what is the difference between using -c and -e in a LFTP script?

- e.g. of -c: [Lftp default timeout and retry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012006/lftp-default-timeout-and-retry)
- e.g. of -e: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32432851/13862759

Can someone point me to where it is in the manual?
https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html

I would like to know in what situations it is correct to use -c, -e or nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These options are described in the ... *OPTIONS* section of the manual:

```
OPTIONS
   -e commands
          Execute given commands and don't exit.
   [...]
   -c commands
          Execute  the given commands and exit. Commands can be separated with a semicolon, `&&'
          or `||'. Remember to quote the commands argument properly in the shell.   This  option
          must be used alone without other arguments (except --norc)
```

The `lftp` command has an interactive mode. If you use `-c`, the `lftp` will exit without starting this interactive mode. If you use `-e`, then it won't exit, and you can continue running commands manually. So you could use `-e` for running some initial setup and then use the interactive mode to do whatever you actually wanted to do (though you could also use the `--rcfile` option for this).

For examples of `-e`, you might have aliases like:

```
alias lftp_debug='lftp -e "debug -o lftp-debug-output 3"'
alias lftp_no_cahce='lftp -e "set cache:enable false"
```

For `-c`, basically any time you have a complete set of commands to execute with `lftp` with no further manual input to be provided, you can use `-c`. You don't need to use `exit` like the example answer you linked to, since `lftp` will automatically exit anyway.